# Is the expression: L={w|w∈{a,b}*& ∃v:www=vv} is a regular language, and why?

Tags: regular-language, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

Is the expression: L={w|w∈{a,b}*&∃v:www=vv} a regular language?

If not, why?

Comment: Have you looked at a few examples of words in $L$?

Comment: As Fabio already said: have you looked at examples of words in $L$? Expand your question with them, maybe formulate a hypothesis, and show more work?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I have, did not find so far because of the odd number of W words, am I missing something? Do you have an example?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have.. Doesn't add up, this is the reason I asked here :)

Comment: Of these words, which ones are in $L$: $\epsilon$, $a$, $aa$ $ab$, $aaa$, $abab$, $abba$?

Comment: ϵ - Yes (?)
aaa - Yes, but does not correlate to www=vv @FabioSomenzi

Comment: If you can't write $www$ as $vv$ then $w \not\in L$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi So this is a classic example for using the "Pumping lemma" in order to prove it wrong?

Comment: At some point you'll go for the proof, not necessarily with the pumping lemma for regular languages.  But it pays off to understand what lies behind the $www=vv$ constraint.  What can you say about the length of $vv$?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Only that length of W is 3 words and of V is 2, no constraints on V. I was looking for a DFA to confirm this

Comment: I didn't ask about $v$, but $vv$.  What's the minimum value of $|vv|$?  What's the next possible value?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi _vv_ has to be at the same length of _www_, it could have been possible if _www_ was symmetric in my opinion

Comment: You are getting a bit closer, but you seem to be carefully avoiding to note the obvious.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Is the obvious is the even number of expressions in _vv_ combined with asymmetry of cases of _www_?

Comment: The obvious is that $vv$ is of even length.  Now if $vv$ is of even length, so is $www$.  What does that say about the length of $w$?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi well, the length of a single work _w_ has to be even in order to "catch" up with _vv_, but here I'm not finding symmetry. example: _ababab != vv_

Comment: In fact $ab$ is not in $L$.  At this point, you can read the spoiler below.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Perfect, thank you for understanding this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to come up with another characterisation of $L$.

**Claim.** $L = \{ uu : u \in \{ \mathtt{a}, \mathtt{b} \}^* \}$.

*Proof.* (⇒) If $w \in L$, write $w = x_0 \cdots x_{n-1}$. Then $$www = x_0 \cdots x_{n-1} x_0 \cdots x_{n-1} x_0 \cdots x_{n-1}.$$ This string has length $3n$, and so if $www = vv$, then $v$ must have length $\frac{3n}{2}$ (so $n$ must be even), and looking at the two halves of $www$ it must be that $$v = x_0 \cdots x_{n-1} x_0 \cdots x_{\frac{n}{2}-1} = x_{\frac{n}{2}} \cdots x_{n-1}  x_0 \cdots x_{n-1}
$$ So $x_0 = x_{\frac{n}{2}}$, $x_1 = x_{\frac{n}{2}+1}$, ..., $x_{\frac{n}{2}-1} = x_{n-1}$. If $u = x_0 \cdots x_{\frac{n}{2}-1}$ we have $w=uu$.

(⇐) If $w = uu$ for some $u \in \{ \mathtt{a}, \mathtt{b} \}^*$, then let $v = uuu$. Clearly $www = (uu)(uu)(uu) = uuuuuu = (uuu)(uuu) = vv$. So $w \in L$.

Using this claim we can show that $L$ is not regular by using the Pumping Lemma, taking for example the string $w=\mathtt{a}^p\mathtt{b}^p\mathtt{a}^p\mathtt{b}^p$ where $p$ is a supposed pumping length for $L$.

Comment: This is great, Thank you!